# javascript alert message not working in android application

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have created an android application with simple webview function. In my html page which webview loads, I am using following script.

```
var message="!!YOU CANNOT COPY ANY TEXT OR IMAGE FROM THIS APP!";
  function clickIE4()
  {
    if (event.button==2)
    {
      alert(message);
      return false;
    }
  }
  function clickNS4(e)
  {
    if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all)
    {
      if (e.which==2||e.which==3)
      {
        alert(message);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (document.layers)
  {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
  }
  else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById)
  {
    document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
  }
    document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
//for disable select option
//document.onselectstart = new Function("alert(message);return false");
```

When I open this in android webview application, it does not show the alert message. It works fine when I open it in normal browser.

Comment: add the java code for the webview too

Comment: Okay.. But which function will work for me???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create `WebChromeClient` and set to `WebiView`. Also override `onJsAlert` method.

```
     WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setMessage(message)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            result.confirm();
                                        }
                                    })
                            .create()
                            .show();

                    return true;
                }
    }

  webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
```

Comment: Thanks! Fyi, I learned that there are 3 different JS dialogs: JsAlert, JsPrompt & JsConfirm. So, for anyone looking around, maybe this info will help - I had to override JsConfirm for the issue I was trying to solve.